# Sec.SE is difficult to navigate with SVG disabled

Tags: support, feature-request

I use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en#whyweneedtor) for browsing the internet. Tor comes with a Firefox-based browser specifically designed to enhance security and anonymity. One of its features is the [security slider](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/security-slider.html), which has three presets for low, medium, and high security. The higher the setting, the more the unsafe features are disabled. This includes the [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) image format, a format which uses vector graphics rather than raster graphics to improve scalability. Unfortunately, SVG parsers are [not very secure](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=svg), and are often abused for arbitrary code execution. Sites which heavily use SVG will thus break at higher security settings.

The Sec.SE site uses SVG for various icons. The difference between the site when it is [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FUiH.png) and when it is [disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdC7i.png) is striking. It seems that this is not a hard requirement for the StackExchange network, as [some sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k0VK.png) seem to work fine and are not using SVG for the various icons.

Is there any workaround which would allow me to utilize full functionality of the site, short of turning down the security slider? Are there currently any plans to provide functionality for browsers which do not support or which have disabled SVG? Sites like Wikipedia provide non-SVG versions of vector graphics for that very reason, and it would be nice if StackExchange could, as well.

Comment: Check out the questions here https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=svg+icons - I think the move to svg has been very deliberate

Comment: Well that's extremely frustrating. It makes the site extremely difficult to use (I can't tell you how many times I accidentally downvoted something when I was trying to favorite it).

Comment: worth asking a specific question on Meta.SE though - focused on the accessibility aspect

Comment: Alright. Will do.